# Using JMeter with service integration bus (SI bus) in Websphere

Tags: jms, websphere, jmeter

I'm trying to use JMS Point-to-Point in JMeter to send messages to a SI bus queue in Websphere.

I'm fairly certain I have the following correct:

```
QueueConnection Factory  
JNDI name Request queue  
JNDI Properties, Initial Context Factory set to com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
```

I have guessed the URL:

```
iiop://ipaddressofWebSphereServer:2809
```

When I run the sampler I get the following error in the jmeter.log:

```
2013/03/14 09:09:01 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Error getting WsnNameService properties javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1444)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:951)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:866)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:546)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:798)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:303)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:597)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1001)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1002)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:986)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:566)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:554)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1330)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1158)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1296)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1877)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1252)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1441)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ipaddressofWebSphereServer
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:385)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:270)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1974)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1999)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1180)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1266)
    ... 25 more

2013/03/14 09:09:01 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Session may not be null while creating message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session may not be null while creating message
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.createMessage(JMSSampler.java:179)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.sample(JMSSampler.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

And I get this error in the orbtrc log:

```
09:09:01.878 com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection connect:403 Thread Group 1-1 ORBRas[default]  java.net.UnknownHostException: <i><b> ipaddressofWebSphereServer</i></b>
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:385)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:199)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:270)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1974)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1999)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1180)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1266)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1330)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1158)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1296)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1877)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1252)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1441)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:951)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:866)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:546)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:798)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:303)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:597)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1001)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1002)
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:986)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:566)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:554)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: ipaddressofWebSphereServer` you are not using the actual IP

Comment: I wrote that for privacy. I did use the actual IP.